# .gitignore Blacklist all by default & manually whitelist pattern not working

Tags: bash, git, gitignore

I'm coding a utility for generating .gitignore files. I'm starting with the whitelist pattern of excluding all by default and then using `!` [(not/negative) rules](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format) to permit paths back in.

Example of a generated `.gitignore`:

```
# Blacklist all by default
*

# Then whitelist what want to track
!.bashrc
!.gitconfig
!.gitignore
!.nvidia-settings-rc
!.p10k.zsh
!.profile
!.zprofile
!.zshrc
!bin/gitignoregen
!credentials.json
!.config/autokey/
!.config/VSCodium/User/snippets/
```

but then running `git add .config/autokey` shows:

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
.config/autokey
```

where `.config/autokey` is a directory containing some files and a subdir. What's going on here and how can I ensure the desired effect?

Comment: `.config/autokey/` is not `.config/autokey`. Try changing it to `.config/autokey`. Is autokey a file or a directory?

Comment: @KamilCuk it's a directory. The docs say: `The slash / is used as the directory separator. Separators may occur at the beginning, middle or end of the .gitignore search pattern.`

Comment: Then maybe `!.config/autokey/**`?

Comment: You may need to run git update index in some scenarios.

Comment: Tried all of these suggestion but still same. Have tried all of: `!.config/autokey` `!.config/autokey/` `!.config/autokey/*` `!.config/autokey/**` and `git update-index`